# Percentage of categories both 100% in Stata?

Tags: graph, stata

I am trying to create a graph looking at the percentage in each age group infected with a  disease, i.e. they have a mean egg count>0 in the variable `eggs10` and then dividing this into those that are `lightly` infected or `heavily` infected.

I have variable for the mean egg count in their urine: `eggs10`

I have a variable for who I am looking at `gender`

I have a variable for intensity : `light` `heavy`

When I type in:

```
gr bar (count) eggs10, stack asyvars over(intense) by(gender) percent
```

it gives me 100% for both males and females as their prevalence of infection! How do I get percentage of those with `eggs10` >0 as y axis?

Answer (score 2):

The effect of `by()` is to treat genders separately. That is, Stata's view is that you asked for percentages to be calculated separately. You may need `over(gender)` here.

(UPDATE) The sample data are rather different from the original example.

```
. input str1 child  Meanegg str1 gender str5 intensity 

child    Meanegg     gender  intensity
1. a  0  M  None 
2. b  55 F  Heavy 
3. c  47 F  Light
4. end 

. encode gender, gen(Gender)
. encode intensity, gen(Intensity)
```

Consider `catplot`, which can download using

```
. ssc inst catplot
```

Try something like

```
. catplot Intensity Gender, asyvars percent(Gender)  stack recast(bar)
```

(SECOND UPDATE) It is important to realise what `graph bar (count)` does. Check out these examples:

```
. sysuse auto
. graph bar (count) mpg
. graph bar (count) mpg , over(foreign)
```

Here is the graph from the second. `(count)` here counts the numbers of observations with non-missing values. This is explained in the help. However, that is rarely what people want here: more commonly, people want counts of the distinct categories of a variable. That can be done with `graph bar`, but it is easier with `catplot` (SSC).

To spell it out for the example graph: the graph tells you that there are 52 non-missing values of `mpg` for domestic cars and 22 for foreign cars. The graph says nothing about what the values of `mpg` actually are.

You could say: But the graph is showing you the frequencies of the distinct categories of `foreign`. Yes; but only in so far as there is a non-missing value of `mpg` for each non-missing value of `foreign`.

[image]

(THIRD UPDATE) (in response to comment August 26) Study the following:

```
. clear

. input var1 str3 var2

        var1       var2
       1. 44 "Yes"
       2. 36 "No"
       3. end

. graph bar (asis) var1, over(var2)

. graph bar (asis) var1, over(var2) percent

. graph bar (asis) var1, over(var2) percent asyvars bargap(20)
```

Comment: Post sample data then.

Comment: Ok so we have children with a variable for: meanegg(numerical variable from 0 eggs (i.e no infection) to 1052 eggs), gender (M or F), intense(categorised as light if meanegg>0 and 'heavy' if meanegg>50). is that what you mean?

Comment: 'Child / Meanegg/ Gender / Intensity
    a     / 0     /   M     / None
    b     / 55    /   F     / Heavy
    c     / 47    /   F     / Light'

Comment: Ok, say for examplet I have:

'code
District      Yes         No
A             44 (55%)    36 (45%) 
'
I basically want to make a bar graph with the percentage of those that say Yes only (y axis) and then in the x axis have the different districts with the percentages of the highest prevalence. Right now, it just gives the numbers of those that are yes i.e for district A it will show 44 as the bar height instead of 55 (as a percent) and when i add percent into the command it puts all the bar heights for all the districts as 100%! its really confusing, does that make sense? @Nick Cox

Comment: Have you studied the answer, and the programs mentioned?